# Linux File Permissions for Other User

Tags: linux, apache

I've just set up LAMP and all seems to be working okay. I am trying to get phpMyAdmin to work. I keep getting a 403 error. I think it is because httpd user does not have access to the appropriate directory. My questions is a reasonably simple one. What command line command do i use to check the permissions for another user?
I.e. i am logged in as root and want to see what the file permissions are for user httpd.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls -l` will list you all files along with the persmissions

a sample entry would be

`d __rwxr-xr-x__ 2 user 4096 Apr 18 00:05 css`

This highlighted part represents permission

First 3 letters -> Owner

Next 3 letters  -> Group

Last 3 letters  -> Others

r -> Readable, w -> writable, x -> Executable.

In this particular example, owner can read, write and execute, group members and others can only read and execute,

Comment: so does that mean if i look at the group section then user x will have those permissions? surely it would vary depending on what permissions are set for the particular user?

Comment: If user x is in the same group as yours, the 2nd set defines their permissions. If not then last 3 letters. It cannot be set to user specific . I.e if user x and y are not in your group(or both are in your group) permission will be same for them. You cannot distinguish between those two

Answer (score 1):

`ls -ld /path` replace 'path' with absolute path to your directory